# How to: Make a Custom Updatepanel Control Which Contains Updateprogress In It

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, custom-controls, custom-server-controls, updateprogress

I use updatepanel and updateprogress in my project. Whenever I add updatepanel to a page, then I should add updateprogress too.

Now I want to make a custom control that include both updatepanel and updateprogress.

If there are any controls like this, Can anyone give me its link. On other hands How to make a custom control likte that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raj Kaimal has a great [example with downloadable source](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/01/08/using-the-updateprogress-control-as-a-modal-overlay.aspx) on his blog. I've used a variant of it for several projects and been very happy overall. It is a model update progress extender control.

Comment: In the link you give, We must add both updatepanel and updateprogress. I want to add only one control which has both control in it.

Comment: Are you sure you want it that way? That makes the control rather inflexible and is a violation of the concept of "seperation of concerns". If you do really want to go that route, you can probably make a custom server control or composite control that acts as a wrapper for the panel and progress controls. You'd need a templated control though to allow you to still put in the content for the panel within your custom control. More info on templated custom controls here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478964.aspx